# Laravel 4.2 Input::file

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, post

Trying to upload file to my test api. For testing I tried to check if input has file and it returns true. The problem is when the code tries to move that file. Search google show almost the same code that I have;

```
if (Input::hasFile('attachments')) {
            $path = base_path().'/assets';
            $files = Input::file('attachments');
            $data = [];

            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $data[] = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

                $uuid = Uuid::uuid1();
                $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $filename = $uuid.'.'.$extension;
                $file->move($path, $filename);
            }

            return Response::json($data);
        } else {
            return 'no file';
        }
```

Doing a post request using Paw multipart give this result on json

[image: Looking at the Paw output and request; clearly the image is attached and has been sent verified by the if (Input::hasFile('attachments'))]

Still can't figure this out. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you so much guys in advance.

Comment: why don't you dump `$files` so you can see what it is

Comment: Here is dd($files)
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)#10 (7) {
  ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  bool(false) ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  string(40) "Screen Shot 2019-12-05 at 1.53.47 PM.png"
 ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  string(9) "image/png
  ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(26) "/private/var/tmp/phpcLdzTa"
  ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(9) "phpcLdzTa"
}

Comment: i dont need to see it, it is for you to see what it is, since the foreach isn't running you are trying to iterate something that isn't what you think it is, like a single upload file object, iterating that object wont do much good ... in short you have a single file, not many, your input is a single input not an array of inputs

Comment: Yup, tried iterating input::file but still getting no value

Comment: `Input::file` does not seem to be iterable. Can you share your view definition?

Comment: there are no view since it's an api. i use paw to send post multipart request

Comment: @RichardC.Alvarez the point is you shouldn't be iterating at all ... it is one file, a single object, what is there to iterate?

Comment: I'm thinking of doing something like if user sends single file then app will be able to upload it or if user selects multiple files then upload will be possible as well

Comment: I tried using the same method with my announcementscontroller and was aboe to post multiple files and iterate through. with that controller i use ajax post formdata

Comment: Upgrade please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are trying to iterate but there is no reason to and `$files` is a single uploaded file.

Just remove the loop since there is nothing to iterate.

```
if (Input::hasFile('attachments')) {
    $path = base_path().'/assets';
    $file = Input::file('attachments');

    $uuid = Uuid::uuid1();
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $filename = $uuid.'.'.$extension;
    $file->move($path, $filename);

    return Response::json($extension);
} else {
    return 'no file';
}
```

If you wanted to have multiple files you would need to have the input setup to be named as an array, `attachments[]`. You are sending `attachments` which is always a single value. If you sent an array then there would potentially be something for you to iterate through.

Comment: I read you answer a bit late and got it figured before i get the chance to read your post. Anyways thank you so much for taking the time to answer and help me

Comment: no worries, you got there in the end, good luck with your project ... i highly highly recommend you upgrade your Laravel installation since 4.2 is extremely outdated at this point

Answer (score 2):

Ok; so something as simple as this `[]` gave me a hard time figuring things out. All I did is add `[]`; instead of just attachments I did attachments[] as post request name and in my controller I retain the `Input::file('attachments')`

[image]

Thank you guys for your guidance and help. Figured things out the hard and tired way.